# Problem with org-insert-link and yas-expand

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

I have a problem when I want to yas-expand a link in `Org-mode` and it has a dash (-) in the text (url and description). Then the snippet break and exits. If I do the same in `fundamental-mode` it works.

## Example

Typing text in fundamental and Org-mode. In fundamental mode:

```
"jira<tab>abc-123" ->
[[https://jira.example.com/browse/ABC-123][ABC-123]]
```

In Org-mode:

```
"jira<tab>abc-123" ->
[[https://jira.example.com/browse/ABC-][ABC-]]123
```

In fundamental-mode I can tab to the last position. But in Org-mode it exits before that.

## Snippet

The [snippet](https://github.com/sdaaish/emacs-demo/blob/master/yas/snippets/fundamental-mode/jira) looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: jira
# key: jira
# --
[[https://jira.example.com/browse/${1:$$(upcase yas-text)}][$1]]$0
```

## Emacs Config

I have this config:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :config (yas-global-mode))
```

Full source for this (my emacs testing area): [Source](https://github.com/sdaaish/emacs-demo/tree/master/yas)

If I change the snippet and remove the last "]", it works again but without becoming a link.

```
From: [[${1:$$(upcase yas-text)}][$1]]$0
To:   [[${1:$$(upcase yas-text)}][$1]$0
```

So it has something todo with `org-insert-link` but I cannot find out if this belongs to **yas** or **org**. Maybe there is a workaround for this. Any ideas how to troubleshoot or fix this?

## Versions

```
yasnippet-20181015.1212
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.0.50/lisp/org/)
GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-03-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the closing bracket be the last element in your template. This avoids your input from becoming a link before you finish typing:

```
[[https://jira.example.com/browse/${1:$$(upcase yas-text)}][$1]${0:$$(insert "]")}
```

Comment: OK, this did solve my issue. Still a bit curious why this was needed though. What causes the different expansions? But that is maybe something I should post to yas on github.

Answer (score 0):

`[[link][description]]` syntax will only be shown as `description` in org-mode, which messed up with the yasnippet placeholder. You can manually switch it to plain text by calling `M-x org-toggle-pretty-entities`, and then `yas-expand` your snippet. You will then find it work well.

I didn't dig into the yasnippet code, so I can only offer a temporary dirty solution. Turn off org-mode font-lock before expansion, and turn it on again after expansion by adding `org-toggle-pretty-entities` to yasnippet builtin `yas-before-expand-snippet-hook` and `yas-after-expand-snippet-hook`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'yas-before-expand-snippet-hook 'org-toggle-pretty-entities)
(add-hook 'yas-after-expand-snippet-hook 'org-toggle-pretty-entities)
```

Maybe you can issue a bug on github.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with `org-toggle-pretty-entities`. I tested your solution but there is no difference.

What I'm trying todo is to upcase the URL and description. I like to write the case-number manually sometimes. But cut&paste is always an option. So maybe this is a bug, have not written a more advanced snippet before.

I checked `view-lossage` and the difference between `fundamental` or `text-mode` and `org-mode` is that the former uses `self-insert-command` and `org` uses `org-self-insert-command`.

So I will probably create an issue on yasnippet for this.